# Add project as library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I want to use [this](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) library in my project. I download the code and place it on my libs folder.
Then I set on app.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project('libs/android-support-v4-preferencefragment')
}
```

as I read in a previous question here but it's not working, android studio tells me it cant find the project

Answer (score 8):

The support-v4-preferencefragment project support local maven repository in this [commit](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment/commit/fab3cf8a0699a5ba45b66d4dcddcf7947239de9b). So, you can deploy it into local maven repository and then reference it in your android studio application project.

1. Clone the library project
  $ git clone https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment.git
2. Deploy aar library into local maven
  $ cd android-support-v4-preferencefragment
  $ ./gradlew uploadArchives
  Now, aar should be within your local maven repository. eg: ~/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4-preferencefragment/1.0.0
3. Reference it in the application project
  Add
  **compile 'com.android.support:support-v4-preferencefragment:1.0.0'**
  within the dependencies block of your app's build.grade.
  If there is no
  **mavenLocal()**
  within your repositories block, add it too.

Comment: thanks for that, mavenLocal() was not enought for me, I had to add `maven { url './.m2repo' }`

Comment: Glad to help, and thanks for the feedback about alternate method to configure local maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the jar file and click `Make Module` it should put the correct information in the gradle file. probably what the problem is that your are missing `.jar` at the end though

Comment: The problem is that there's no jar file. On the README.md, you can read: "Includes resources so add this as a library project to your project." and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: oh I see, the project is not made for android studio so you cannot implement it that way, it is made for eclipse which is a totally different app structure so what you have to do is manually mode everything from the library to your project

Comment: if the developer does not give you a gradel dependencie and there are resources in the library then its a safe bet that its not for android studio. jar libraries dont really matter because they can always be imported

Comment: You can. Just add new android library module, and then ut the src in the java folder, and then res folders inside res folder..... Then use build.gradle to add libraries, and it's done